# how to limit the number of rows in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to limit the number of rows in a textarea, in order to make sure, that the entered text fits in the layout. The maximum amount of characters per line is 83.
I found several solutions([like this one](http://jsbin.com/ufeyom/2/edit)) but none of them work properly(after 5 rows a reached, it is still possible to enter large words which continue in new lines).

So I received the following script to at least limit the number of characters:

```
function sliceText(element)
{
    var maxlength =15;
    if(typeof maxlength !== 'undefined' && maxlength !== false)
    {
       var val = $(element).val();
       val = val.replace(/\r\n/g, '__NL__')
         .replace(/\n/g, '__NL__')
         .replace(/\r/g, '__NL__')
         .replace(/__NL__/g, '\r\n');

       if (val.length > maxlength)
       {
           $(element).val(val.slice(0, maxlength));
           var lastChar = $(element).val()[$(element).val().length - 1];
           if(lastChar == '\n')
           {
                $(element).val(val.slice(0, maxlength - 2));
           }
       }
    }
}

<textarea name="name" onkeyup="sliceText(this)" ></textarea>
```

My idea is to extend this with adding "`83-((number of characters already entered) modulo 83)`" for every newline.

Unfortunatly I have almost no knowledge of `Javascript`, so I would be glad if someone had a solution for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236333/textarea-limit-characters-per-line-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: does not work either :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a working solution:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9x5Fb/2/)

JS:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("splitLines");
textarea.onkeyup = function() {
var lines = textarea.value.split("\n");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].length <= 16) continue;
var j = 0; space = 16;
while (j++ <= 16) {
  if (lines[i].charAt(j) === " ") space = j;
}
lines[i + 1] = lines[i].substring(space + 1) + (lines[i + 1] || "");
lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, space);
 }
textarea.value = lines.slice(0, 6).join("\n");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

HTML

```
<form>
    <textarea onKeyPress="return charLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return characterCount(this)"  rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>
<p><strong><span id="charCount">83</span></strong> more characters available.</p>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var maxLength=83;
function charLimit(el) {
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) return false;
    return true;
}
function characterCount(el) {
    var charCount = document.getElementById('charCount');
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) el.value = el.value.substring(0,maxLength);
    if (charCount) charCount.innerHTML = maxLength - el.value.length;
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like this also only limits the number of characters

Comment: @user2968538, what i have left in this?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gtsq74zy/1/

JS:

```
function getLineNumber(textarea) {
    return textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionStart).split("\n").length - 1;
}

$(function(){
    var chars = 0;
    var ln = 0;
    var lines = [];
    var check = 1;
    $('#ta').keyup(function(e){
        lines = $(this).val().split('\n');
        ln = getLineNumber($(this)[0]);
        chars = lines[ln].length;
        check = 83 - chars;
        $('#ct').text(check);        
    }).keydown(function(e){
        lines = $(this).val().split('\n');
        ln = getLineNumber($(this)[0]);
        chars = lines[ln].length;
        check = 83 - chars;
        if(chars >= 0 && e.which != 8) check--;

        if(check < 0 && e.which != 8){
            $(this).val($(this).val() + '\n');
            lines = $(this).val().split('\n');
            ln = getLineNumber($(this)[0]);
            chars = lines[ln].length;
            check = 83 - chars;
            if(chars >= 0 && e.which != 8) check--;
        }
        $('#ct').text(check);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="ta" cols="85" rows="7"></textarea>
<br/>
Chars Left: <div id="ct">83</div>
```