# Don't write a character in a textarea after a onkeypress check

Tags: javascript, textarea

I've got a textarea with onkeypress function call, and i would like to check if the numbers of rows are more than 10: if they are, i would't like to write the character. How can i "stop" the writing after the function check?

```
<textarea id="textAr" maxlength="350" rows="6" onkeypress="check(this)"></textarea>

    function checkLines(textArea){
            var text = textArea.value;
            var linesNumber = text.split("\n").length;

           // alert("number of rows is: " + linesNumber);

            if(linesNumber > 10){
                ???
            }
     }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Max characters in textarea with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292235/max-characters-in-textarea-with-jquery) UPDATE - sorry, wrong link, try this one: [how to limit the number of rows in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447381/how-to-limit-the-number-of-rows-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop a character being written, you can use the [event.preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) method. We can do this by adding an [event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) to the element in place of an onkeypress attribute.

```js
function checkLines(event){
    var text = this.value;
    var linesNumber = text.split("\n").length;

    // alert("number of rows is: " + linesNumber);

    if(linesNumber > 10){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
document.querySelector("#textAr").addEventListener("keypress", checkLines);
```

You can also use [event.key](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_key.asp) to fetch the key being pressed. This would allow you to only prevent new lines with the enter key (`"Enter"`).

```js
    if(linesNumber > 10 && event.key == "Enter"){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```