# Remove one line from contenteditable div if written line gets removed

Tags: javascript, html

If you have written text inside `<div contenteditable></div>`, how can I determine if one line is removed?

I thought about counting the line breaks and then if one line break is removed I can shrink the size of the `<div>`.

You can see this behaviour in WhatsApp. If you write text in WhatsApp the textarea grows to a specific size. If you're deleting text it shrinks.

How would you achieve this?

Don't show code, just explain.

Comment: If the linebreaks are created by automatic text wrap, it's extremely hard to detect them. Why not use a DIV with content adaptive size?

Comment: Don't set height to the div

Comment: @Teemu `Why not use a DIV with content adaptive size?` What do you mean by that? I want the `div` to grow to a specific size and then it should stop.

Comment: Div element adapts the height of its content automatically if you don't define the height explicitly. You can stop the height growing at a maximum height by setting some CSS code that you didn't want to see ..

Comment: if its textarea, add the limit to each line, like a line can only contain 100 characters.
and just get the total lines based on the text/limit. 
you take help from this answer as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236333/textarea-limit-characters-per-line-jquery-or-javascript/5236402#5236402

Comment: @Teemu Actually I want to see it, if it's just css. I was talking about js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of a DIV element adapts the height of its contents automatically, if the height is not explicitly set. You can achieve what you need with CSS only. Just set the minimum and maximum height for the box. The overflow needs to be set so that you can scroll the text when it grows out of the box. `word-break` is set to break very long words to fit inside the pad so, that the horizontal scrollbar should never appear.

```css
.pad {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="pad" contenteditable></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the main Idea is let the div have the space to grow , the height will be adapted automatically

```css
.messagePane {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    display: grid;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.messageBox {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="messagePane">
  <div class="messageBox" contenteditable>
    Type your message here 
  </div>
</div>
```