# Textarea limit characters for each row in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to limit the number of characters for each row in a textarea with javascript.

I have seen a few examples in here but doesn't do exactly what I am looking for.

I have wrote something which does it ok only if you add every time more than the limit.

In other words, I have a limit of 10 characters per row, if you always type at least 10 is working fine, but if you want to type 5 characters in first row and press enter to move to next line it wont let me it keeps redirecting me to first row and can't really figure it out how to overcome this.

```
<textarea onchange="Validate(this)" onkeyup="Validate(this)" class="txtValidation15   textarea" id="txtpr1-0" cols="30" rows="20" name="txtpr1-0"></textarea>

function Validate(control)
 {
    var limit = 10;
    var v = control.value; //var v = $(this).val();
    var vl = v.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").length;
    var newtext="";
    for (var i = 0; i < v.length ; i = i + limit)
    {
        v = v.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        var n = v.substr(i,limit)
        if(i+limit < v.length)
            n= n + '\n';
            
        newtext += n;
    }
    control.value = newtext;
}
```

Comment: How about just specifying `cols` attribute instead?

Comment: tried that didn't work, you can add more than the specified cols, also tried the wrap method and no luck

Comment: Similar question: [javascript - How to limit number of characters per line in text area to a fixed value - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236213/how-to-limit-number-of-characters-per-line-in-text-area-to-a-fixed-value/19876218#19876218)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into lines first so you're counts are per-line instead of aggregate.

```
function Validate(control) {
    var limit = 10;
    var v = control.value; //var v = $(this).val();
    var lines = v.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/);
    var newtext = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length ; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];
        if(line.length > limit) {
          line = line.substr(0,limit);
        }
        newtext += line;
    }
    control.value = newtext;
}
```

Pasting this function into the textarea truncates it to this:

```
0123456789
function V
    var li
    var v 
    var li
    var ne
    for (v
        va
        if

        }
        ne
    }
    contro
}
```

Comment: with that it allows me to type more than the limit :(

Comment: It does work, sorry, my bad, was a missing bracket. Thanks a mill!

Answer (score 0):

What about doing something like this?

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function Validate(control)
 {
    var limit = 10;
    var v = control.value; //var v = $(this).val();
    var vl = v.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").length;
    var newtext="";
    for (var i = 0; i < v.length ; i++)
    {
    if (i%limit==0){
        v = v.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        var n = v.substr(i,limit)
            n= n + '\n';
        newtext += n;
        }
    }
    control.value = newtext;
}
```