# Need help adapting code from jQuery to Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, textarea

I found some code here: [Textarea limit characters for each row in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015312/textarea-limit-characters-for-each-row-in-javascript)

I want to use it in my project, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it work in Angular, particularly setting the directives.

Here's the relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aSU7x/

Do I just change
    `onchange="Validate(this)" onkeyup="Validate(this)"`
to
    `ng-change="Validate(this)" ng-keyup="Validate(this)"`
?

I'm still not too familiar with Angular, and I'm only slightly more familiar with jQuery. What would I have to do with the scope, controller, etc.? What would a proper Angular implementation of this code look like? Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea of calling a function in angular using scope and $event

```js
angular.module('changeExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.keyupfnc = function(evt) {
        console.log(evt.which);
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="changeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type="text" ng-keyup="keyupfnc($event)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got the following error when I tried:

Argument 'ExampleController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: No idea. I copy/pasted exactly what was up there.

Comment: If you have an Angular app, you need to integrate this into it, not just copy and paste it in.  You should have an app and a controller...

Comment: Yes. I definitely don't know how to do that. That is why I wrote this question. I have a controller and I have the textarea thing. I ended up with two modules and two controllers: the one with my main app, and, below it, the module you provided.

Comment: So you need to do some Angular tutorials... All you should be copying is the `input` and pasting it into the html and copying the `$scope.keyupfnc` and pasting that into the controller.

Comment: And you need reading comprehension lessons. Thanks for the "help". :)

Comment: @ep84 Don't be freaking rude, people are helping you for free. You really need to learn the basics of Angular and tutorials will teach you this stuff you are asking. It is how I learned it a few months ago. Plenty of tutorials that will walk you through building an app and they will teach you how to wire up events and work with directives.