# Min and max doesn't work with my text input

Tags: html, html-input

I have got this HTML:

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td class="bold"> Full name</td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="Fullname" name="Fullname" width="50" min="1" max="15" size="50"> </td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold">Message </td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="Message" name="Message"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="submit" value="Send"</td>
    <td> <input type="submit" value="Delete"</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I got asked to set 50 columns and 5 lines for the input of the **message** but I don't know what that even means.

I tried to set a `min` and `max` for my inputs and it didn't work. Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: 1) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text 2) don't have idea

Comment: @sinisake where do we use attributs min and max then ? :P

Comment: input type="number" i would say...

Comment: a side note - do not rely only on clientside input validations... but do serverside validation too if you really need text with specific minimum and maximum length...

Comment: One possible solution for your task can be achieved through a small javascript.
If feasible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015312/textarea-limit-characters-for-each-row-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minlength="1" maxlength="15"` to set the number of characters that can be entered into a text field.

Columns and lines can only be specified for `<textarea>`s. There you can use `rows="5" cols="50"` to specify the size of the textarea.

See the snippet below:

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td class="bold"> Full name</td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="Fullname" name="Fullname" width="50" minlength="1" maxlength="15" size="50"> </td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bold">Message </td>
    <td> <textarea type="text" id="Message" name="Message" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="submit" value="Envoyer"</td>
    <td> <input type="submit" value="Effacer"</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `minlength`?
When using text you might want to use `minlength` and `maxlength` to force the text's length.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" minlength="8"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

(From w3schools)

See this example:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_minlength