# Need jquery or javascript to restrict per line length in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I have following html textarea:

```
<textarea name="splitRepComments"   cols="20" rows="3" ></textarea>
```

on which I have applied maxlength restriction using jQuery. that Function is as below:

```
var max = 100;
$('#splitRepComments').bind("keypress", function(e) {


    if (e.which < 0x20) {
        // e.which < 0x20, then it's not a printable character
        // e.which === 0 - Not a character
        return; // Do nothing
    }
    if (this.value.length == max) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (this.value.length > max) {
        // Maximum exceeded
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, max);
    }
});

$('#splitRepComments').bind("paste", function(e) {


    setTimeout(function() {

        var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
        e.which = 50; // # Some key code value
        $('#splitRepComments').trigger(e);
    }, 100);

});
```

My hurdle is I have requirement in which we want user to enter only 10 characters in each row (line). And after that input should be taken next line.

This function also should obey maxlength restriction of textarea.

In addition I have tried below solution from SO but is not taking input to next line.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19876218/1487469

I have [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjc0gh0w/5/) ready for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this:

    var max = 100;
    var characterPerLine = 10;

    $("textarea[name='splitRepComments']").bind("keypress", function(e) {

        if (e.which < 0x20) {
            // e.which < 0x20, then it's not a printable character
            // e.which === 0 - Not a character
            return; // Do nothing
        }
        //calculate length excluding newline character
        var length =  this.value.length - ((this.value.match(/\n/g)||[]).length);
        if (length == max) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if (length > max) {
            // Maximum exceeded
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, max);
        }
        if (length % characterPerLine == 0 && length!=0 && length < max)                           {
            $(this).val($(this).val()+'\n');
        }

    });
```

Comment: When I set max = 20; First line I can enter 11 and 2nd line 9. Did you check this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in plain JavaScript (you can transform it to JQuery as you please), I tried to incorporate comments for each statement :

```
var manageTextAreaSize = function manageTextAreaSize(fieldId, cols, rows){ 
    // Get textarea text value 
    var value = document.getElementById(fieldId).value; 
    // Save current cursor position (for mid text typing) 
    var currentPosition = document.getElementById(fieldId).selectionStart; 
    // Arraye will be used to save separate text lines 
    var lines = []; 
    // Remove newline characters (by splitting the text using newline character as separator then joining by blank) 
    // then cut off extra characters (for limited number of rows only) 
    value = value.split("\n").join(""); 
    if(rows){ 
      value = value.substr(0, cols * rows); 
    } 
    // If text length is superior to max number of characters (more than one line) 
    if(value.length > cols){ 
      // Split text by lines of max character length 
      for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i += cols){ 
        lines.push(value.substr(i, cols)); 
      } 
      // Reassemble text into the text are by joining separate lines 
      document.getElementById(fieldId).value = lines.join("\n"); 
      // Reposition cursor back to previously saved position (before resizing text) 
      document.getElementById(fieldId).selectionStart = document.getElementById(fieldId).selectionEnd = currentPosition; 
    } 
    // If text length is inferior to max number of characters (less than on line) 
    else if(value.length < cols){ 
      // Do nothing ! 
      return; 
    } 
    // If text length is equal to max number of characters (one line only) 
    else{ 
      // Go to next line 
      document.getElementById(fieldId).value += "\n"; 
    } 
  };
```

Usage : directly to HTML on input event (in the exemple below : 35 characters per line for maximum of 6 lines)

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" cols="70" rows="20" style="resize: none" oninput="manageTextAreaSize(this.id, 35, 6);"></textarea>
```

NB : I didn't test this without resize so be careful when using this solution with resize !