# Limit number of characters per line in multiline field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I need functionaliy which will have TextArea with

1. In each line there must be maximum of 30 chars
2. Don't want to trim any value while typing, next characters grater than 30 in a line need appear automatically in next line

Below code I'm using, but it trims the next line 1st character while pasting a line with 30+ characters.

```
<textarea id="textareainput"></textarea>


var input= document.getElementById("textareainput");
var lines = input.value.split("\n");
var start = input.selectionStart;
var end = input.selectionEnd;

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  if (lines[i].length <= 30) continue;
  var j = 0; space = 30;
  while (j++ <= 30) {
    if (lines[i].charAt(j) === " ") space = j;
  }
  lines[i + 1] = lines[i].substring(space + 1) + (lines[i + 1] ? " " + lines[i + 1] : "");
  lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, space);
}

input.value = lines.slice(0, lines.length).join("\n");

if (start == end) {
  input.setSelectionRange(start, end);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236213/how-to-limit-number-of-characters-per-line-in-text-area-to-a-fixed-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit number of characters per line in text area to a fixed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236213/how-to-limit-number-of-characters-per-line-in-text-area-to-a-fixed-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following(your code with small change)

```
   $('#textareainput').on('input focus keydown keyup', function() {
    var input= document.getElementById("textareainput");
var lines = input.value.split("\n");
var start = input.selectionStart;
var end = input.selectionEnd;

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  if (lines[i].length <= 30) continue;
  var j = 0; space = 30;
  while (j++ <= 30) {
    if (lines[i].charAt(j) === " ") space = j;
  }
  lines[i + 1] = lines[i].substring(space) + (lines[i + 1] ? " " + lines[i + 1] : "");
  lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, space);
}

input.value = lines.slice(0, lines.length).join("\n");


});
```

Updated solution due to cursor positioning problem:

```
 function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  }
  else if (input.createTextRange) {
    var range = input.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
    range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
    range.select();
  }
}

function setCaretToPos (input, pos) {
  setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
}
 function formatStr(str, n) {
   var a = [], start=0;
   while(start<str.length) {
      a.push(str.slice(start, start+n));
      start+=n;
   }
  return a.join("\n");
}

$('#textareainput').on('input focus keydown keyup', function() {
    var input= document.getElementById("textareainput");
var lines = input.value.split("\n");
var start = input.selectionStart;
var end = input.selectionEnd;

var v = input.value;
        var vl = v.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); //remove all newlines  

        input.value = formatStr(vl,30);

        var lines1 = input.value.split("\n");

        if (start == end)   {
            if(lines1.length!=lines.length)
                setCaretToPos(input, end+1);
            else
            setCaretToPos(input, end); 
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you IStepashka. I tried the code and result is getting correct, but the selection range is not correct. as I'm using **input.setSelectionRange(start, end);**. Can you please help me to solve the issue

Comment: Please explain why do you need line  input.setSelectionRange(start, end)? The cursor will be at the end of the characters line anyway...

Comment: I need it because if the user need to add some comment/add additional text at the starting. If I'm not setting the SelectionRange, the cursor automatically redirecting to end while trying to type any where between the entered text.

Comment: Thank you for the the solution. I went through the solution, but it is spiting the word 10 characters in each line. I want a solution like if user type e.g "Hello, I Like You" (counting 
from 1st Char 'H', the 10th char is 'L' but it is whole word 'Like',  
it shouldn't break and continue to next line e.g. Currently the word come as below  
Hello, I L  
ike  
Need to enhance the code to come the whole word to next line like below :    
Hello, I  
Like You

Comment: Also, if I type  1234567890  1234567890  it is spliting the lines correctly, but while I'm trying to type "ab" at beginning  it should come as below <br/> ab12345678<br/>
9012345678  
90  
but with the current code it is getting as  
a1b2345678  
9012345678  
90

Comment: I had updated formatStr function in the code for solving the word spliting issue. but the previous setSelectionRange issue came with the above code

Comment: I will try to look into cursor issue later

Comment: Sorry,cannot seem to find any solution to solve those issues. Maybe others could help you with this