# how to add line break after 10 characters with line limit

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add line break on a textarea through JavaScript. I'm not looking for any CSS solutions.

1. While user type from keyboard or paste a string on TextArea the Line break should happen after 10 characters.
2. If the character count (10) is end at the middle of an word, the
   whole word should move to to next line.
3. If the word is longer then 10 characters then it can be span across multiple lines.
4. Count space as character.
5. User can entered up to 6 lines

Sample input text -

```
All new year of the thousand
```

```js
var lineCountLimit = 6;
var lineLengthLimit = 10;

$(".message").on("keydown paste", function (e) {
  var element = $(e.target);
  var str = $(element).val();
  // 
});
```

```css
textarea{
  display:block;
  width: 500px;
  height:350px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Almost duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236213/how-to-limit-number-of-characters-per-line-in-text-area-to-a-fixed-value/19876218#19876218 except for the whole-word requirement. (**but** what should be done with words longer than 10 characters?)

Comment: It was already mentioned on question itself = "If the word is longer then 10 characters then it can be span across multiple lines."

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that you will need to add linebreak after every 10 characters in every situation in this `textarea`, then you can do something like this using regex [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ut86wv9q/):

```
$('.message').keyup(function() {
  var new_stuff = $(this).val();
  new_stuff = new_stuff.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, ""); // clean out newlines, so we dont get dups!
  var test = new_stuff.replace(/(.{10})/g, "$1\n"); // Here
  $(this).val(test);
});
```

Comment: Failed! sample test- "all new years", its breaking "years" words, not move whole word to a new line

Comment: It does, have you tried the demo link I have mentioned?

Comment: yes, run my sample text as given on question

Comment: is there way to include unicode characters?  like chinise?

Comment: any word? for world breaking?

Comment: Let me see what's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple (perhaps inefficient) code:

```js
var lineCountLimit = 6;
var lineLengthLimit = 10;

$(".message").keyup(function (e) {
var element = $(e.target);
var str = $(element).val();
if (str.length!=0)
{
    var words = str.match(/(\w+)/g);
    var numOfLines = 0;
    var currentString = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
    var listOfLines = [];
    while (numOfLines < lineCountLimit)
    {
        if (/\s/.test(currentString[lineLengthLimit]))
        {
            listOfLines.push(currentString.slice(0,lineLengthLimit));
            currentString = currentString.slice(lineLengthLimit);
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentString.length>lineLengthLimit)
            {
                for (count = lineLengthLimit; count >= 0; count--)
                {
                    if (/\s/.test(currentString[count]))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (count>0)
                {
                    listOfLines.push(currentString.slice(0,count));
                    currentString = currentString.slice(count);
                }
                else
                {
                    listOfLines.push(currentString.slice(0,lineLengthLimit));
                    currentString = currentString.slice(lineLengthLimit);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                listOfLines.push(currentString);
                break;
            }
        }
        numOfLines+=1;
    }
    $(element).val(listOfLines.join('\n'));
}
});
```

Comment: where is line limit?

Comment: Your code did not work, its breaking word at the middle!

Comment: What do you mean by line limit?

Comment: user can entered up to 6 lines

Comment: Thanks! Looks like now while move to next line there was a white space at the beginning, which should remove..

Comment: If you could use my sample input - "All new year of the thousand".

Comment: all others looks good only there was two points - while I enter a character like "a" and then press enter key and then type "b", the "b" moved up to line one, "b" should be on line two as I hit enter. Second if I type "all new year", the year is moving to next line with a whitespace before, I just wanted to remove it. Additionally as I mentioned on question like all flow should work on "paste" event too, but its not working while right click and paste a text there.